# Macro does not do all the functions it’s suppose to do

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Apologies if this is a simple question but I have a macro that divides as it should but it will not copy and paste the contents from one cell to another cell as it’s suppose to do.  See below for examples with expected result.

```
Sub master2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim pair As Variant, accumulator As Variant
    Dim findFifteen As Double
    Dim remainder As Long, found As Long

    found = 1

    For Each pair In Range("B30, F30, J30")
        If Right(pair, 2) = 15 Then
            If pair.Offset(0, 2) <= 12 Then
                findFifteen = pair.Offset(0, 2)     / 12
                remainder = 0
            Else
                findFifteen = 1
                remainder = pair.Offset(0, 2)    Mod 12
            End If

            For Each accumulator In Range("A14,     B14, C14, D14, E14, F14, G14, H14, I14, J14, K14, L14")
                If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) =     Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-") - 1)) Then 
                    accumulator.Value =     accumulator.Value + remainder
                End If
                accumulator.Value =    accumulator.Value + findFifteen
            Next accumulator

            Range("E" & found).Value = pair
            found = found + 1
        End If
    Next pair

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Example with expected result.

As per my Excel image, my macro is suppose to find specified cells that contain a 15 as the last number. Cell B30 has the number 7-15 in it. I need the macro to go to the cell below (B31 and use the number 1 in this example) and then search the following cell range: E1:E12 to find a 1 (cell E1). Once found place the 7-15 and increase the last digit by 1 (so it becomes 7-16) in the adjacent cell to the right (F1). Do the same with all cells: B30, F30 and J30 but only if they contain a 15 (1-15 or 7-15 etc.) as the last number.  After this delete all contents in cell B30, C30, D30. There are are two examples in my Excel sheet where the same thing needs to happen.

[image: excel image]

Comment: Have you stepped through? Is this right `If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) =    ` as the offset is row 13 which is full of letters?

Comment: On closer examination, your description doesn't seem to tally with your code.

Comment: The macro works except for the end where it's suppose to move the contents form cells B30, F30 and J30. Which part of my description is not correct?

Comment: Hi, I just did the step through and it finds the cell where the contents of either cells B30, F30 and J30 are to be moved to and then it does nothing. Thanks o much for your help.

Comment: Which line is it that you don't think is working? I can't see where you are adding 1 to the last digits. Sorry but I'm confused.

Comment: I think the problem line is: Range("E" & found).Value = pair.  Using my Excel example cell B30 has the 7-15 in it. It has to be moved to cell F1 and be increased by 1 so it becomes 7-16.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, I can't follow what you're doing, but this will give you "7-16" in E1 if B30 contains 7-15 (and similarly for the other cells). I've stripped out most of your code so I don't know if this is a full answer

```
Sub master2()

Dim pair As Range, found As Variant, v As Variant

For Each pair In Range("B30, F30, J30")
    If Right(pair, 2) = "15" Then
        v = Split(pair, "-")
        found = Application.Match(pair.Offset(1),Range("E1:E12"), 0)
        If IsNumeric(found) Then
            Range("F1:F12").Cells(found).Value = v(0) & "-" & v(1) + 1
        End If
    End If
Next pair

End Sub
```

Comment: I tested your code and it works but I need the rest of the code to make it all work. The great news is I think you may have helped me to solve the problem on my own. If you can bear with me and if I can ask for, I hope, a small amount of help we might be done here. In my original code the line “Range("E" & found).Value = pair”  can we change that E (I assume that’s the search criteria) to search specific cells E1 to E12 or use the range E1:E12.  I’ve tried to make the change but it will not work. Also, after each copy and paste of cell B30 etc.  delete all contents in cell B30, C30, D30 etc.

Comment: Yes, but where in column E should it go?

Comment: I'm getting there using VBA but I have a ways to go so please bear with me. So if I'm correct in saying that it searches column E for the correct cell i would say the range is E1:E12 or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: In the code above, when `found=1` the value in B30 is put in E1, and then F30 goes in E2 etc. What I'm asking is what determines the output cell? What are you searching E1:E12 for?

Comment: Sorry now I know what you're referring to. As per my Excel image, my macro is suppose to find specified cells that contain a 15 as the last number. Cell B30 has the number 7-15 in it. I need the macro to go to the cell below (B31 and use the number 1 in this example) and then search the following cell range: E1:E12 to find a 1 (cell E1). Once found place the 7-15 and increase the last digit by 1 (so it becomes 7-16) in the adjacent cell to the right (F1).

Comment: Huge favor, could you amend the original code above. I've tried with your changes it says no way.

Comment: Don't think I can because (1) I don't understand all of your code and (2) if my code above doesn't work, it stlll won't work. What does "it says no way" actually mean?

Comment: I just tried your new code with the change and it doesn't work. No errors or anything it just doesn't copy and paste or delete the cells after pasting. It runs with no problems. No debug problems or anything. Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: Hi, it works with one minor adjustment. the copy and and paste is occurring in the cell range E1:E12 (this is just a reference column, see Excel sample sheet if not clear), I need it in the column to the right of that one F1:F12. Also, it's not deleted the 3 cells when finished. Thank-you again.

Comment: To the moderator: could you close this post. Reason: SJR in his own words "Don't think I can because I don't understand all of your code."